# showing cursor position not value

Tags: android, list, cursor

I have the below code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  mSelectedContact = (NameOfList)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
  if(mSelectedContact != null){
    String dn = mSelectedContact.getDisplayName();

    // Talking about this line here:
    String num = (mSelectedContact.getPhoneNumbers().toString()); 

    Log.i(TAG, dn + num);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);
    LinearLayout Details = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_item, null);
    TextView DisplayName = (TextView)Details.findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);                                       
    DisplayName.setText((dn) + (num));

    mainLayout.addView(Details);
  }
}
};
```

I want the marked line to show the value of the phone numbers but it shows the cursor position like:

```
John Doe[android@40598908, android@40598800]
```

How would I get the value of the numbers?

Comment: What is the method `getPhoneNumbers` returning?

Comment: A List of phone numbers of the selected contact but I'm not sure what type it is (i.e int, string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe You just need to write String num = (mSelectedContact.getPhoneNumbers()); 
without toString() , because in Java toString() method returns a string representation of object like android@40598908.

Comment: If I do that, I get the error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<PhoneNumber> to String.

If I change the type to List, the results display the same as above.

Comment: So ok I got it. Your method mSelectedContact.getPhoneNumbers() returns List of PhoneNumber object. So in your code You need to write                                                List<PhoneNumber> num = mSelectedContact.getPhoneNumbers(); Then Your PhoneNumber object must have a method which returns that phone number as String for example .getPhoneNumbers() . Then You need to call it and You will get Your desired phone numbers as string

Comment: Thank you for making me understand it better! Only problem is that the code doesn't have a method that returns all the numbers as a string, it just has one for the primary number:

public String getPrimaryNumber(){
  final PhoneNumber primaryNumber = ListUtils.getFirstOrDefault(mPhoneNumbers, new PhoneNumberFilterByAnyValid());
  if(primaryNumber != null){
   return primaryNumber.getNumber();
  }
  return null;
 }

How would I go about modifying that for all the numbers and not just the first or default?

Comment: I think it is ok if you return just first or default number.

Comment: i need to access all the numbers :) I can do the default easily!